# Versions of @angular/compiler-cli and typescript could not be determined. The most common reason for this is a broken npm install

Tags: angular

My project in angular2 but when i run the project following error is produce

Versions of @angular/compiler-cli and typescript could not be determined.
The most common reason for this is a broken npm install.

Please make sure your package.json contains both @angular/compiler-cli and typescript in
devDependencies, then delete node_modules and package-lock.json (if you have one) and
run npm install again.

I getting this error when i run the project.below are my envs details

```
Angular CLI: 1.6.8
Node: 8.2.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.4
... core

@angular/cli: 1.6.8
@angular/common: 2.2.3
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.10
@angular/compiler: 2.2.3
@angular/forms: 2.2.3
@angular/http: 2.2.3
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.2.3
@angular/platform-browser: 2.2.3
@angular/router: 3.1.2
@angular/tsc-wrapped: 0.5.2
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.42
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.29
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.52
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.9.8
@schematics/angular: 0.1.17
typescript: 2.0.2
webpack: 3.10.0
```

below are the stpes which i taken to run the project

```
1)npm install -g @angular/cli@latest 
2)npm install 
3)ng serve
```

my logs

```
Versions of @angular/compiler-cli and typescript could not be determined.
The most common reason for this is a broken npm install.

Please make sure your package.json contains both @angular/compiler-cli and typescript in
devDependencies, then delete node_modules and package-lock.json (if you have one) and
run npm install again.
```

i wasted lot of time on this but can't get solution.if any idea please give me suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must update your dependencies. Angular-CLI 1.5+ doesn't support Angular 2 anymore. Must run at least Angular 4 and also I think at least Typescript 2.6. If you want to check what dependencies you need for a new project simple run

```
ng new NewApp
```

Edit: for clarification: You are trying to use the version 1.6.8 of the angular-cli with angular 2. Angular 2 is not supported by that version of the cli anymore. You have to update those packages. The best way to do so would be to create a new project using the cli. Doing the following

1. Open a command prompt and navigate to some location on your computer
2. Run the command ng new SomeAppName where SomeAppName is the name of the new project. The cli will now generate a new Project and Folder with that name and all the latest dependencies.
3. Open your current not working project and locate the package.json
4. Open the fresh generated project and locate the package.json
5. Compare the package.json files from 3 and 4 and update your dependencies
6. run npm i

The alternative way is to downgrade your angular-cli to version 1.3 for instance

1. npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
2. npm i -g @angular/cli@1.3

Comment: I tried but not solve the problem here is my package.json

Comment: The angular-cli 1.6.8 does not support angular 2.x.x. You must run angular 4++. Just run the command as stated above, you will get a whole new project with a proper configuration and all the latest angular-packages. From there on you can compare it to your projects configuration.

Comment: Glad it helped. It would be nice for others to exactly know what you did to fix it, since I posted two possible solutions in that scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Here is sample `package.json` file, change the versions as per your need.
And, first of all delete your `node_modules` folder created by `npm install`, change `package.json` as specified, and then do `npm install`.

I'm pasting whole code here because you showed only a part of your, the problem might be that you haven't mentioned `devDependencies` in your `package.json`.

```
  {
    "name": "ng-app",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
      "ng": "ng",
      "start": "ng serve",
      "build": "ng build",
      "test": "ng test",
      "lint": "ng lint",
      "e2e": "ng e2e"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
      "@angular/animations": "^5.1.3",
      "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.3",
      "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
      "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
      "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
      "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
      "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
      "@angular/material": "^5.0.3",
      "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
      "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
      "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
      "angular2-text-mask": "^8.0.4",
      "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
      "core-js": "^2.4.1",
      "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
      "jquery": "^3.2.1",
      "ngx-popover": "0.0.16",
      "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
      "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "@angular/cli": "1.6.0",
      "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
      "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
      "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
      "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
      "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
      "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
      "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
      "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
      "karma": "~1.7.0",
      "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
      "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
      "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
      "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
      "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
      "protractor": "~5.1.2",
      "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
      "tslint": "~5.7.0",
      "typescript": "~2.4.2"
    }
  }
```